# Padding errors using OpenSSL for encrypt/decrypt with Keys extracted from Digital Cert

Tags: windows, encryption, openssl, cryptography, certificate

I am using some command line Open SSL commands to encrypt and decrypt data using Public and Private keys extracted from a Digital Cert.   When I try to decrypt I get PKCS padding errors.  Can someone tell me where I'm going wrong?

These are the command I've been using:

a) Extract Public key:  openssl x509 -pubkey -noout -in xxxxx.cer  > xxxxxpublickey.pem

b) Extract Private Key:openssl pkcs12 -in xxxxxx.pfx -nocerts -out xxxxxprivatekey.pem -nodes

c) Encypt a key (.bin file): openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -in kenkey.bin -out kenkey_Key -pass file:xxxxxpublickey.pem

d) Decrypt key produced in c) openssl rsautl -decrypt -hexdump -in kenkey_key -inkey xxxxxprivatekey.key -out aeskey.txt

This produces errors like this:

> RSA operation error 3248:error:0407109F:rsa
>   routines:RSA_padding_check_PKCS1_type_2:pkcs decoding
>   error:.\crypto\rsa\rsa_pk1.c:273: 3248:error:04065072:rsa
>   routines:RSA_EAY_PRIVATE_DECRYPT:padding check
>   failed:.\crypto\rsa\rsa_eay.c:602:

Comment: Step (c) doesn't do what you think it does, you look to be encrypting the .bin file with AES, using the contents of the public key .pem as a *password*. It's very unlikely this is what you want.

Comment: Hi. Oh! Really? You're right, that's not what I want. Could you tell me how that OpenSSL command should look?

Comment: Probably much like step (d) except in encrypt mode and using the public key rather than private.

Comment: This seemed to cure it:   "openssl rsautl -encrypt -inkey xxxxxpublickey.pem -pubin -in kenkey.bin -out key.bin.enc"    Thanks for the pointer!